# cannot pass php variables to javascript: SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I am trying to pass a php variable to a javascript file like this:

```
 var base = "<?php echo $_SESSION['idata'];  ?>";
```

But when consoling I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

Any advice could help, thanks.

Comment: var base = "<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['idata'];  ?>";

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize session

```
var base = "<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['idata'];  ?>";
```

Comment: This is working perfectly locally but in production base is being set to: <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['idata']; ?>    any ideas please?

Comment: just for testing creates a new file test.php with just one line var base = "<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['idata'];  ?>";

Comment: what is your response ?

Comment: in my computer I have: var base = "teste ";

Comment: because in my case I previously adjusted $_SESSION['idata'] = 'test'